# How to reduce the time of df.describe() method execution for a spark dataframe with huge number of columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For one of my data validation script , I am doing df.describe() on the input dataframe for preparing data profile (where df is my input dataframe). For a particular dataframe of 3000 columns (but only 16 records) , this particular part is taking on an average 3 mins. When I have checked the spark history , this part has executed in two stages with each of having 1 task. On Event timeline, **99.99% of the time is as  "executor computing time"**. Shuffle write and shuffle read are only in kb and not even taking a millisecond to complete. While checking the DAG execution flow for this stage , it gave me a flow as follows:

```
stage 1: (~1.4 min)
    scan csv --> project --> sortAggregate --> exchange(shufflle write)
stage 2(~1.6 min):
    Exchange(shufflle read)--> sortAggregate
```

So from this I can understand that sortAggregate on 3000 columns is causing the delay. What should I do to bring down this execution time.

Comment: do you need all columns? You can also pass a list of columns to `describe`

Comment: @Raphael Roth  Yeah I know , we can just pass selected columns , but I need complete columns to be passed. since  I am preparing a complete data profile for every feed file . And  describe ()  is the first to that